# Is traffic within an Azure VNET encrypted?

Tags: azure, ssl, encryption, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I'm looking for some information on Azure Virtual Network security for data in transit.

We use Application Gateway to terminate the TLS connection (443) and forward the (unecrypted) request (80) to a backend server in the same virtual network but in a different subnet.

Microsoft states that VNETs are private and secure.

I could not find any information if traffic within a VNET is encrypted. That it wouldn't be possible to inspect traffic from outside of the VNET for anyone.

The HTTP request itself is not encrypted, but would the VNET traffic transporting the request be encrypted?

*For inter-region traffic the documentation states: data-link layer encryption using MACsec*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Datacenter data-in-transit is encrypted at data link layer using MACsec which means other customers or data sniff with in MS Azure is not possible. VNET traffic is part of your network and Transport or Application layer encryption is customer responsibility. You can use Ipsec or tls at transport layer

Answer (score 1):

Please note that all vnet's are isolated from each other. It means traffic from one VNET cannot reach traffic from another VNET by default and it requires peering. Local IP's under VNET are private IP's and they are non routable.
Traffic inside VNET is not encrypted but you can use HTTPS, SMB 3.0 or other protocols to encrypt traffic between services. More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-overview

Comment: I understand that traffic within the VNET is not encrypted.

I want to know what does it mean that VNETS are isolated/private.
How is Azure ensuring that my VNET is isolated when my services within the VNET are communicating.

How is it ensured that this traffic can not be sniffed e.g. by other Azure customers.

Is VNET traffic in the Azure datacenter encrypted (similar to a VPN)?

Comment: Other Azure customers do not have access to your VNET at all so they cannot snife your traffic. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview

Comment: My question is, how does Azure ensure that others don't have access? Is data travelling in my VNET in the Azure datacenter encrypted? Similar to traffic via a VPN? They don't state anything in the documentation how this isolation is achieved

Comment: Traffic in your VNET is not encrypted. In regards to isolation please look here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/isolation-choices

Comment: Thank you, understood. That means if a VLAN router (which seems to be a shared device across tenants) is compromised, there would be the possibility to sniff unencrypted network traffic within my VNET.